# Nagios with Munin services gives unknown

Tags: nagios, munin

On an Debian Wheezy updated server, I'm using the backports of the following packages :

- Nagios : nagios3 (3.4.1-5~bpo7+1)
- Munin : munin (2.0.25-1~bpo70+1)

And nsca (2.9.1-2) to trasmit data from Munin to Nagios in order to process alerts.

Nagios is working fine with the following configured Munin services :

```
# generic service template definition
define service{
    name                           generic-munin-service ; The 'name' of this service template
    use generic-service
    check_command                  return-unknown!"No Data from passive check"
    active_checks_enabled          0       ; Active service checks are disabled
    passive_checks_enabled          1
    parallelize_check               1
    notifications_enabled           1
    event_handler_enabled           1
    is_volatile                     1
    notification_interval           120
    notification_period             24x7
    notification_options            w,u,c,r
    check_freshness                1
    freshness_threshold            360
    flap_detection_options         n
    max_check_attempts             2
    register                       0   ; DONT REGISTER THIS DEFINITION - ITS NOT A REAL SERVICE, JUST A TEMPLATE!
    ;first_notification_delay      6    ; Delay first notification for false positives (will execute 2 checks : munin sends 1 check every 5 minutes)
}


define service {
    hostgroup_name                munin
    service_description           Disk latency per device :: Average latency for /dev/sda
    use generic-munin-service
    notification_interval         0 ; set > 0 if you want to be renotified
}

define service {
    service_description           Disk latency per device :: Average latency for /dev/sdb
    use generic-munin-service
    notification_interval         0 ; set > 0 if you want to be renotified
}

define service {
    hostgroup_name                munin
    service_description           Disk usage in percent
    use generic-munin-service
    notification_interval         0 ; set > 0 if you want to be renotified
}

define service {
    hostgroup_name                munin
    service_description           Inode usage in percent
    use generic-munin-service
    notification_interval         0 ; set > 0 if you want to be renotified
}

define service {
    hostgroup_name                munin
    service_description           File table usage
    use generic-munin-service
    notification_interval         0 ; set > 0 if you want to be renotified
}
```

But when I add further services which are available on all monitored hosts too, they will be labelled as **UNKNOWN** in Nagios:

```
define service {
    hostgroup_name                 munin
    service_description            Memory usage
    use generic-munin-service
    notification_interval          0 ; set > 0 if you want to be renotified
}

define service {
    hostgroup_name                 munin
    service_description            CPU usage
    use generic-munin-service
    notification_interval          0 ; set > 0 if you want to be renotified
}
```

I've already found out that depending on the munin plugin graph title format, Nagios may not understand the incoming data, that's why I've updated the packages on the server to the backports version of Wheezy, since Munin 2.0.7 should clean all titles.

I also tried to debug with a higher debug level, and the log shows :

```
[1434122043] SERVICE ALERT: HostIJZI4;Memory usage;UNKNOWN;HARD;2;INCONNU
```

But I may need your help for going further.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to update your packages, Nagios Core is currently in 4.1.1 and you are using an older version.

They fixed a lot of things, maybe your issue is now patched : https://www.nagios.org/projects/nagios-core/history/4x/